# Indicate the presence of dupe hammer in profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, dupehammer

Let's compare hammers for a bit:

[image]    [image]

New user who is oblivious to the way Stack Exchange sites work does not really know the difference between the symbols, so to get more details about the intriguing user he will visit the profile page.

In case of diamond, it's crystal clear on first glance:

> [image]

Moderator is a common term, anyone knows, curiosity satisfied. However...

> [image]

Nothing in this profile indicates that this user can single handedly close questions. Not in a first glance, and not in the 100<sup>th</sup> for most people except those few who are familiar enough with Stack Exchange.

Therefore, I suggest to add something like this:

> [image]

The gold icons would have proper tooltips same way the icon in the close message already does, or have only one even in case of multiple gold badges.

Comment: Proper titles is important here, either next to the name or as a tool-tip on the proposed badge icons next to the name. Otherwise, I wouldn't understand what those gold circles up there mean.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau true, I meant tooltips, edited to make it more clear now.

Comment: Cue questions: why do some profiles have yellow circles? Yes, you proposed a tooltip... but given that the feature is meant for users who did not read the tooltip in close banner, how will that help?

Comment: @900sit valid point, but people would more likely try to read tooltip in the profile page. If you can come with short word to describe those users, it can be placed instead of "moderator".

Comment: I don't have gold tag badges myself, but if I did, I probably would not one hanging over there by my name. "Does this user have a dupehammer?" is not nearly on the same level of importance as "is this user a moderator?"

Comment: I have *eight* such hammers, with more on the way. It'd get mighty crowded up there if you put all of them there. And Jon Skeet has *52*... Them's a lot of hammers!

Comment: Also, just because I have gold badges does not elevate me to the level of a moderator, really. Having something next to my name just like moderator does feels like a little too much honour.

Comment: @Martijn this specific power was moderator-only, it's a binding close vote so not "too much honour" IMO. Maybe just a single icon to not clutter the design, with tooltip like "This user has binding duplicate close vote for [tag A, tagB, ...]"

Comment: @ShadowWizard: take into account that tooltip would need to scale to 52 badges; better to then use `binding duplicate close vote for x tags, click for a list`.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a good idea, with slight modifications:

- Only display one gold badge icon. Multiple icons appearing there for each gold tag badge would just be irritating.
- Have the icon (or maybe add some text to replace the "Moderator" text that associates the diamond) link to the user's badges tab, sorted by class. This will list all of their gold tag badges first, followed by their regular gold badges, etc. It provides an easy, already-existing list of what gold tag badges the user currently possesses. (Example: [my profile here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson?tab=badges&sort=class))
- Have the tooltip indicate *how many* gold tag badges (dupe hammers) the user has, and that they can click to find out for which tags.

Comment: Thanks, those are valid suggestions. I gave it some thought, but couldn't come with any proper word instead of "moderator", thus was left only with showing the gold icon.